# Кроссбраузерное воспроизведение музыкальных файлов на чистом HTML

Tags: html, css

Есть такой лендинг:
https://perfect-goods.com/total_war_rome/

У которого музыкальное сопровождение во время просмотра страницы функционирует в браузерах:
Mazilla
Internet Explorer
Microsoft Edge

При этом саундтрек не воспроизводится в браузерах:
Opera
Yandex Browser
Google Chrome

Подключение к файлам и сами файлы можно увидеть на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Что я упустил из виду и что требуется выполнить - что бы воспроизведение музыкального файла функционировало кроссбраузерно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузеры блокируют автовоспроизведение аудио так как это раздражает пользователей.  Однако если следовать некоторым правилам то это всё-таки возможно. Ознакомьтесь с этим документом
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: а у вас случайно на заметке нет работающего кроссбраузерного универстального решения - я так понял что необходимо указывать какие то настройки и скармливать браузерам.
+ то что вы скинули это относится к гуглу а с остальными как быть?

Comment: Могу дать, на JS есть вариант запустить, но только играть тихо будет. Либо кликджекингом, это тоже на JS. Вроде работает

Comment: тоесть с обычной громкостью вариантов нет в природе?